# Why I'm still able to use ssh reverse tunnel after closing reverse ssh connection?

Tags: ssh

I have created a reverse ssh tunnel to connect to a computer behind NAT using:

`ssh -R 9050:localhost:22 user@middleserver`

in the destination system. I closed the terminal that I entered this command in. But I'm still able to connect to the destination computer using

`ssh destuser@middleserver -p 9050` from my system

Is this normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes with OpenSSH, the `ssh` client won't terminate until *all* its open forwarded connections are all closed, in either direction. As long as any connection is open it will continue to accept new connections (which is at least surprising, and arguably a defect).

Use the sequence `~#` after a CR and OpenSSH will show you which forwarded connections are open at that time. Use `~.` to terminate `ssh` if it persists after logout/exit/^D due to open connections, this only applies if you start `ssh` yourself in a terminal emulator. If your GUI/WM environment starts `ssh` sessions for you, it may close windows even though there are processes still running.